# Difference between partition key, composite key and clustering key in Cassandra?

Tags: database, cassandra, cql

I have been reading articles around the net to understand the differences between the following `key` types. But it just seems hard for me to grasp. Examples will definitely help  make understanding better.

```
primary key,
partition key, 
composite key 
clustering key
```

Comment: I found [this article](http://intellidzine.blogspot.com/2014/01/cassandra-data-modelling-primary-keys.html) which contains many detailed explanations around these concepts.

Comment: [This article](http://datascale.io/cassandra-partitioning-and-clustering-keys-explained/) also points out clearly these terms.

Comment: @duong_dajgja URL shared by you above is broken, can you please edit comment with valid/useful URL?

Comment: @realPK The link somehow has gone. But I found another link for you here https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-primary-partition-and-clustering-key-in-Cassandra.

Answer (score 1427, accepted):

There is a lot of confusion around this, I will try to make it as simple as possible.

The primary key is a general concept to indicate one or more columns used to retrieve data from a Table.

The primary key may be ***SIMPLE*** and even declared inline:

```
 create table stackoverflow_simple (
      key text PRIMARY KEY,
      data text      
  );
```

That means that it is made by a single column.

But the primary key can also be ***COMPOSITE*** (aka ***COMPOUND***), generated from more columns.

```
 create table stackoverflow_composite (
      key_part_one text,
      key_part_two int,
      data text,
      PRIMARY KEY(key_part_one, key_part_two)      
  );
```

In a situation of ***COMPOSITE*** primary key, the "first part" of the key is called ***PARTITION KEY*** (in this example **key_part_one** is the partition key) and the second part of the key is the ***CLUSTERING KEY*** (in this example **key_part_two**)

**Please note that both partition and clustering key can be made by more columns**, here's how:

```
 create table stackoverflow_multiple (
      k_part_one text,
      k_part_two int,
      k_clust_one text,
      k_clust_two int,
      k_clust_three uuid,
      data text,
      PRIMARY KEY((k_part_one, k_part_two), k_clust_one, k_clust_two, k_clust_three)      
  );
```

Behind these names ...

- The **Partition Key** is responsible for data distribution across your nodes.
- The **Clustering Key** is responsible for data sorting within the partition.
- The **Primary Key** is equivalent to the **Partition Key** in a single-field-key table (i.e. **Simple**).
- The **Composite/Compound Key** is just any multiple-column key

Further usage information: [DATASTAX DOCUMENTATION](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/create_table_r.html)

---

Small usage and content examples
***SIMPLE*** KEY:

```
insert into stackoverflow_simple (key, data) VALUES ('han', 'solo');
select * from stackoverflow_simple where key='han';
```

**table content**

```
key | data
----+------
han | solo
```

***COMPOSITE/COMPOUND KEY*** can retrieve "wide rows" (i.e. you can query by just the partition key, even if you have clustering keys defined)

```
insert into stackoverflow_composite (key_part_one, key_part_two, data) VALUES ('ronaldo', 9, 'football player');
insert into stackoverflow_composite (key_part_one, key_part_two, data) VALUES ('ronaldo', 10, 'ex-football player');
select * from stackoverflow_composite where key_part_one = 'ronaldo';
```

**table content**

```
 key_part_one | key_part_two | data
--------------+--------------+--------------------
      ronaldo |            9 |    football player
      ronaldo |           10 | ex-football player
```

But you can query with all keys (both partition and clustering) ...

```
select * from stackoverflow_composite 
   where key_part_one = 'ronaldo' and key_part_two  = 10;
```

**query output**

```
 key_part_one | key_part_two | data
--------------+--------------+--------------------
      ronaldo |           10 | ex-football player
```

Important note: the partition key is the minimum-specifier needed to perform a query using a `where clause`.
If you have a composite partition key, like the following

eg: `PRIMARY KEY((col1, col2), col10, col4))`

You can perform query only by passing at least both col1 and col2, these are the 2 columns that define the partition key. The "general" rule to make query is you must pass at least all partition key columns, then you can add optionally each clustering key in the order they're set.

so, the valid queries are (**excluding secondary indexes**)

- col1 and col2
- col1 and col2 and col10
- col1 and col2 and col10 and col 4

Invalid:

- col1 and col2 and col4
- anything that does not contain both col1 and col2

Comment: @CarloBertuccini: Thanks for the explanation. if you could supplement your tables with some examples of how the data look in table for each, it will help a lot and just a one line where this could be used. Thanks again

Comment: @brain storm: For what is possible to do I've added a few informations and usage examplese. It's not easy to represent data in a single post

Comment: woow! This is excellent. Is having composite key same as saying secondary index?

Comment: A secondary index allows queries without any part of the primary key, even without partition key. With a composite you can't perform queries only using clustering keys

Comment: To create a secondary index: CREATE INDEX myindex ON mytable(acolumn);

Comment: what is the partition key here: `PRIMARY KEY((col1, col2), col10, col4))` Is it (col1,col2) or `col1` what will be row key for this instance?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58033/discussion-between-brain-storm-and-carlo-bertuccini).

Comment: another question posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24968823/how-to-construct-range-query-in-cassandra

Comment: why 'col1 and col2 and col4' this is invalid key combination for query.

Comment: As I wrote -- <<The "general" rule to make query is you have to pass at least all partition key columns, then you can add each key in the order they're set.>> -- since col10 is defined before col4 you have to pass it to query also for col4

Comment: @CarloBertuccini :

why col1 and col2 and col10 is valid 
and  col1 and col2 and col4 invalid ? you say minimum with mention col1 and col2 in condition,,,thx

Comment: @ihsansat because you can specify columns in where clause only following the order in which they are defined in table. Since col10 is defined before col4 you can not perform a query using col4 if you don't put in your where also col 10. Again: The "general" rule to make query is you have to pass at least all partition key columns, then you can add each key in the order they're set

Comment: @carlo-bertuccini Is it true that i can add secondary index to any column and then can execute any cql which I want? Or this method will be slower than using COMPOSITE/COMPOUND KEYs like PRIMARY KEY((col1, col2), col10, col4))?

Comment: You can add secondary indexes but that does not mean you can execute "any" cql query -- and more: before creating a secondary index you should count till 10 ... 000 ..... :)

Comment: @carlo-bertuccini I understand that. But is using COMPOSITE/COMPOUND KEYs is more productive/elegant solution then secondary index? Or doesn't matter?

Comment: Secondary indexes are implemented as local indexes -- they are not distributed in the cluster. Each node of the cluster is responsible for storing secondary indexes of data it owns. For this reason a query on sec.index might involve all nodes in the cluster

Comment: @CarloBertuccini Ordering of clustering keys is the only thing that matters.. Please update your answer to add `col10 and col1 and col2`, `col1 and col10 and col2`, `col2 and col10 and col1 and col4` etc.. as valid :)

Comment: @karthikmanchala you misunderstood the answer. I'm not saying you should write the query with col1 before col2 and col2 before col10, I am saying that you can't query with col2 without col1, and you can't query with col10 without col1 and col2. The CQL parser will obviously accept where col10 = some and col2 = something and col1 = somethingelse.

Comment: [Updated DATASTAX documentation for Cassandra 2.0 and 2.1](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/create_table_r.html)

Comment: How can ```select * from stackoverflow where key_part_one = 'ronaldo';``` work when you don't have both columns of the primary key?

Comment: It works because the definition of the table is saying that k_part_one is the only partition key (it is referred to the second create statement where k_part_two is the clustering key). Cheers

Comment: Excellent answer and extremely helpful to everyone. Implementation of secondary indexes and their impact on query performance was not obvious to me. I wish this info was added right into the docs. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for a detailed level explanation. One more thing I wanted to add over here is: with Composite keys if you have more then one records with same partition key with different clustering key then even though in querying it shows us multiple rows but Cassandra will store it as one row only. All the data associated with that partition key is stored as columns in the datastore

Comment: This is a great answer, I loved the explanations thank you. Do you think the `clustering key` should be called `clustering column/s` some documentation refer as anything after the partition key as `clustering column/s`

Comment: Awesome answer. Very helpful in my journey in understanding Cassandra Modelling.

Comment: Thanks I physically felt pieces is getting onto places while reading this information.

Answer (score 211):

Adding a summary answer as the accepted one is quite long. The terms "row" and "column" are used in the context of CQL, not how Cassandra is actually implemented.

- A **primary key** uniquely identifies a row.
- A **composite key** is a key formed from multiple columns.
- A **partition key** is the primary lookup to find a set of rows, i.e. a partition.
- A **clustering key** is the part of the primary key that isn't the partition key (and defines the ordering within a partition).

Examples:

- `PRIMARY KEY (a)`: The partition key is `a`.
- `PRIMARY KEY (a, b)`: The partition key is `a`, the clustering key is `b`.
- `PRIMARY KEY ((a, b))`: The composite partition key is `(a, b)`.
- `PRIMARY KEY (a, b, c)`: The partition key is `a`, the composite clustering key is `(b, c)`.
- `PRIMARY KEY ((a, b), c)`: The composite partition key is `(a, b)`, the clustering key is `c`.
- `PRIMARY KEY ((a, b), c, d)`: The composite partition key is `(a, b)`, the composite clustering key is `(c, d)`.

Comment: This actually answers a query I've had for a while, how do you define a composite partition key (multi-column) without a clustering key, the trick is to use double-parenthesis! ```PRIMARY KEY ((a, b))```

Comment: I've e-mailed this concise and readable summary way too many times... it's textbook material!

Answer (score 18):

In Cassandra, the difference between primary key, partition key, composite key, clustering key always makes some confusion. So, I am going to explain below and co relate to each other's. We use CQL (Cassandra Query Language) for Cassandra database access.
Note: - Answer is as per updated version of Cassandra.

**Primary Key: -**
In Cassandra there are 2 different ways to use primary Key.

---

```
CREATE TABLE Cass (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    name text 
);
```

---

```
Create Table Cass (
   id int,
   name text,
   PRIMARY KEY(id) 
);
```

---

In CQL, the order in which columns are defined for the PRIMARY KEY matters. The first column of the key is called the partition key having property that all the rows sharing the same partition key (even across table in fact) are stored on the same physical node. Also, insertion/update/deletion on rows sharing the same partition key for a given table are performed atomically and in isolation. Note that it is possible to have a composite partition key, i.e. a partition key formed of multiple columns, using an extra set of parentheses to define which columns form the partition key.

**Partitioning and Clustering**
The PRIMARY KEY definition is made up of two parts: the Partition Key and the Clustering Columns. The first part maps to the storage engine row key, while the second is used to group columns in a row.

```
CREATE TABLE device_check (
  device_id   int,
  checked_at  timestamp,
  is_power    boolean,
  is_locked   boolean,
  PRIMARY KEY (device_id, checked_at)
);
```

Here device_id is partition key and checked_at is cluster_key.

We can have multiple cluster keys as well as partition keys too which depends on declaration.

Comment: You could have given some credit to your sources (2013 = older than your post): http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2013/01/11/primary-keys-in-cql.html

Answer (score 12):

**Primary Key**: Is composed of partition key(s) [and optional clustering keys(or columns)]
**Partition Key**: The hash value of Partition key is used to determine the specific node in a cluster to store the data

**Clustering Key**: Is used to sort the data in each of the partitions (or responsible node and its replicas)

**Compound Primary Key**: As said above, the clustering keys are optional in a Primary Key. If they aren't mentioned, it's a simple primary key. If clustering keys are mentioned, it's a Compound primary key.

**Composite Partition Key**: Using just one column as a partition key, might result in **wide row issues** (depends on use case/data modeling). Hence the partition key is sometimes specified as a combination of more than one column.

***Regarding confusion of which one is mandatory***, which one can be skipped etc. in a query, trying to ***imagine Cassandra as a giant HashMap*** helps. So, in a HashMap, you can't retrieve the values without the Key.

Here, the **Partition keys** play the role of that key. So, each query needs to have them specified. Without which Cassandra wouldn't know which node to search for.

The **clustering keys** (columns, which are optional) help in further narrowing your query search after Cassandra finds out the specific node (and its replicas) responsible for that specific **Partition key**.

Answer (score 7):

In brief sense:

**Partition Key** is nothing but **identification** for a row, that identification most of the times is the single column (called **Primary Key**) sometimes a combination of multiple columns (called **Composite Partition Key**).

**Cluster key** is nothing but **Indexing** & **Sorting**. Cluster keys depend on few things:

1. What columns you use in where clause except primary key columns.
2. If you have very large records then on what concern I can divide the date for easy management. Example, I have data of 1million a county population records. So, for easy management, I cluster data based on state and after pincode and so on.

Comment: Partition Key is NOT an identification for A row... it identifies a bunch of rows all of which have the same partition key

Comment: @wmac, if there is no clustering key and if there is just one partition key, then isn't the partition key identification of the row ?

Answer (score 2):

Worth to note, you will probably use those lots more than in similar concepts in relational world (composite keys).

Example - suppose you have to find last N users who recently joined user group X. How would you do this efficiently given reads are predominant in this case? Like that (from offical [Cassandra guide](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling)):

```
CREATE TABLE group_join_dates (
    groupname text,
    joined timeuuid,
    join_date text,
    username text,
    email text,
    age int,
    PRIMARY KEY ((groupname, join_date), joined)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (joined DESC)
```

Here, **partitioning key** is compound itself and the **clustering key** is a joined date. The reason why a **clustering key** is a join date is that results are already **sorted** (and stored, which makes lookups fast). But why do we use a compound key for **partitioning key**? Because **we always want to read as few partitions as possible**. How putting **join_date** in there helps? Now users from the same group and the same join date will reside in a single partition! This means we will always read as few partitions as possible (first start with the newest, then move to older and so on, rather than jumping between them).

In fact, in extreme cases you would also need to use the hash of a *join_date* rather than a *join_date* alone - so that if you query for last 3 days often those share the same hash and therefore are available from same partition!

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to have a word, since none of the answers really helped me *understand*, what those actually mean.

`Partition key` **groups** your data based on its uniqueness. *Everyone who has the same key goes into the same partition*.

`Clustering key`, on the other hand, uniquely identifies a row *inside a partition*.

E.g., we have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE temperature_readings (
  sensor_id text,
  time timestamp,
  temperature float,
  PRIMARY KEY (sensor_id, time)
)
```

in which we'll store readings from a temperature sensor `sensor_id` at `time`.

`sensor_id` is the **partition key** and `time` is the **clustering key**.

We can load many rows with the same `sensor_id` and they will be stored in the same partition, sorted by their `time`. For each sensor they are going to be "grouped together" (and [physically stored on the same Cassandra node](https://www.scylladb.com/glossary/cassandra-partition-key/)).

I'm imagining it like this:

```
+-----------+------------+--------------
| sensor_id | time       | other row data...
+-----------+------------+--------------
|  1        | 1682615843 |
|           +------------+
|           | 1682615848 |
|           +------------+
|           | 1682615890 |
+-----------+------------+
|  2        | 1682615111 |
|           +------------+
|           | 1682615123 |
+-----------+------------+
| 99909     | 1682615688 |
|           +------------+


 and so on...
```

*(Even though it is not correct in the sense of how actual data gets stored physically on the disk.)*

Answer (score 1):

Primary Key: Like in many databases, it is a unique key in a table, essentially it means, for any two records in a table, primary key cannot be same. Database, in this case Cassandra is designed to make sure that this condition is true in all situations. So if you try to write a record with PK1 as primary key, if there is a record already present with same key PK1, it will get overwritten, else a new record will be created.

Partition Key: It is a construct of distributed databases(where data of a single table is divided into multiple parts called partitions). Partitions are then distributed across nodes using a distribution strategy(usually, hash of partition key) to get infinite scaling capabilities. Having said that, partition key is a set of columns of a record that decides which partition this record will belong to. And hence, partition key decides the physical location of a record across distributed cluster of nodes.

Clustering Key: Clustering Key decides the order of records in a particular partition. So, if there are 10K records in a partition, clustering key will decide the order in which these 10K will be physically stored in a sorted manner.

Example:

Lets say you have a table in Cassandra to store sales event of an e-commerce website.

```
[order_id, item_id, quantity, amount, payment_id, status, order_time, PRIMARY KEY( (order_id, item_id), order_time)] with clustering ORDER BY (order_time DESC);
```

So here,

Primary Key is  `((order_id, item_id), order_time)` and it will decide the uniqueness of a record in table.

Partition Key is `(order_id, item_id)`, hash of this tuple will decide the partition of this record and it location on distributed cluster.

Clustering Key is `order_time`, for a particular partition, records will be ordered by `order_time` in descending order. So if you do a `Limit 1` cql query for a particular partition, you will get the record with max timestamp always.

Composite key is just a term to specify that Primary key of a table is not single column, but multiple columns.

Primary key is a combination of partition and clustering key.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** This is answer is specific to DynamoDB, however the concepts apply to Cassandra as well, since both are NoSQL databases.

When you create a table, in addition to the table name, you must specify the primary key of the table. The **primary key** uniquely identifies each item in the table, so that no two items can have the same key.

DynamoDB supports two different kinds of primary keys:

**Partition key** – A **simple primary key**, composed of one attribute known as the partition key.

DynamoDB uses the partition key's value as input to an internal hash function. The output from the hash function determines the partition (physical storage internal to DynamoDB) in which the item will be stored.

In a table that has only a partition key, no two items can have the same partition key value.

**Partition key and sort key** – Referred to as a **composite primary key**, this type of key is composed of two attributes. The first attribute is the partition key, and the second attribute is the sort key.

DynamoDB uses the partition key value as input to an internal hash function. The output from the hash function determines the partition (physical storage internal to DynamoDB) in which the item will be stored. All items with the same partition key value are stored together, in sorted order by sort key value.

In a table that has a partition key and a sort key, it's possible for two items to have the same partition key value. However, those two items must have different sort key values.

A **composite primary key** gives you additional flexibility when querying data. For example, if you provide only the value for Artist, DynamoDB retrieves all of the songs by that artist. To retrieve only a subset of songs by a particular artist, you can provide a value for Artist along with a range of values for SongTitle.

> **Note:** The partition key of an item is also known as its hash
> attribute. The term hash attribute derives from the use of an internal
> hash function in DynamoDB that evenly distributes data items across
> partitions, based on their partition key values.

The **sort key** of an item is also known as its range attribute. The term range attribute derives from the way DynamoDB stores items with the same partition key physically close together, in sorted order by the sort key value.

Reference - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.PrimaryKey

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra uses a special type of primary key called a **composite** key (or **compound**
key) to represent **groups** of related rows, also called partitions. The composite key
consists of a partition key, plus an optional set of clustering columns. The partition key
is used to determine the nodes on which rows are stored and can itself consist of multiple
columns.