# How to understandr primary key in Apache cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

i new for use apache cassandra, i have install cassandra and use cqlsh in my laptop

i used to create table using :

```
create table userpageview( created_at timestamp, hit int, userid int, variantid int, primary key (created_at, hit, userid, variantid) );
```

and insert several data into table, but when i tried to select using condition for all column (i mean one by one) it's error

maybe my data modelling wrong, maybe anyone can tell me how create data modelling in cassandra

thx

Comment: "when i tried to select using condition for all column (i mean one by one)" -- how do you mean? Can you show an example?

Comment: Select * from userpageview where userid=10; it make error :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to read about partition keys and clustering keys.  Cassandra works much differently than relational databases and the types of queries you can do are much more restricted.

Some information to get you started: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949676/difference-between-partition-key-composite-key-and-clustering-key-in-cassandra) and [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause).