# Cassandra where clause on simple columns

Tags: cassandra, where-clause, cql, non-relational-database

I'm new to Cassandra and I'm having a difficulty to use a simple select query on a very basic table. For example,

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE date > '2015-10-10';
```

on this given table:

```
CREATE TABLES cars ( id int primary key, name varchar, type varchar, date varchar);
```

I'm able to use the `=` operator but not the `>, < >=, <=`. 
I have read on this subject including [this article](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause) and [this overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949676/difference-between-partition-key-composite-key-and-clustering-key-in-cassandra) on the different key types, but it is still unclear to me. In the table above, `date` is a SIMPLE column, why can't I use the `WHERE` clause like I would use it in a regular RDBMS?

Comment: You're incorrect in saying that the = operator works on date. Will is right below where you can only use the WHERE clause on columns in the priamry key (clustering columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cassandra, you can only use the WHERE clause on Keys, that's why your query doesn't work.

Take a look on this article [that is similar to your problem](http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/we-shall-have-order/), you'll understand that Cassandra data model isn't the same as the relational one.

Comment: The link http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/we-shall-have-order/ does not work anymore. I guess the same content is in https://www.datastax.com/blog/we-shall-have-order now.

Comment: Also on Secondary Indexes Columns. But as you said, recommended only on columns part of the Primary Key.