# How can I specify primary key using pycassa?

Tags: cassandra, pycassa, nosql

I am trying to add a primary key using **pycassa**. I can do that using CQL3 but I cannot find any document that explains how to do this with Pycassa in the web. I googled too much, didnt find anything.

- Does anyone know how can I specify which will be my primary key of my column family using Pycassa?
- Also, I have another question. Is it possible to have a large primary key? For example PRIMARY KEY(id, name, last_name, age).

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have a large primary key ("*composite key*"). In your example, `id` would then be the *partition key*, and `name`, `last_name`, `age` are *clustering keys*. All fields combined make the *primary key*.

For a very good explanation of the different types (and naming) of keys, check out [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24953331/1485715).

[This post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pycassa-discuss/8BOphzLIerw) gives an example of how to create a composite key:

```
system_manager.create_column_family(..., key_validation_class="CompositeType(UTF8Type, Int32Type)")
```

For your data then, I would guess:

```
system_manager.create_column_family(..., key_validation_class="CompositeType(Int32Type, UTF8Type, UTF8Type, Int32Type)")
```

I have not used pycassa myself, but the [pycassa documentation](https://pycassa.github.io/pycassa/tutorial.html) has this example:

```
col_fam.insert('row_key', {'col_name': 'col_val'})
```

So I'll venture a guess for your case (adding a couple of columns for the sake of completeness):

```
col_fam.insert((id,name,last_name,age), {'firstname':first_name,'city':city})
```