# How do partition keys work?

Tags: indexing, cassandra, primary-key, database-partitioning

I am new to Cassandra and I read that the primary key is the same thing as the partition key.

My question is simple, in this case:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_name varchar PRIMARY KEY,
  password varchar,
  gender varchar,
  session_token varchar,
  state varchar,
  birth_year bigint
);
```

As the partition key is **responsible for data distribution accross your nodes**, how will the data be distributed by `username` in this case?

Comment: You can read about difference between primary key and partition key here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949676/difference-between-partition-key-composite-key-and-clustering-key-in-cassandra

Comment: Please read my question again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, The PRIMARY KEY is *not* the same as the partition key.  The partition key is a part of the PRIMARY KEY.  And yes, it is the part which determines how a row is distributed across the cluster.

> how will the data be distributed by username in this case?

If I CREATE your table, insert some values and query it I can get a bit of a window into the distribution process by using the `token` function in my SELECT:

```
> SELECT token(user_name), user_name FROM user2;

 system.token(user_name) | user_name
-------------------------+-----------
    -5077180869401877077 |   Patdard
    -4874582970682694928 |      Robo
     4639906948852899531 |      Bill
     4645660266327417866 |       Bob
     4877648712764681009 | Valentina
     5726383012007749221 |   Helcine
     7724711996172375448 |  Jebediah

(7 rows)
```

Let's assume that I have 5 nodes.  In Cassandra each node is responsible for a primary token range.  Let's assume the following:

```
1)  5534023222112865485 to -9223372036854775808
2) -9223372036854775807 to -5534023222112865485
3) -5534023222112865484 to -1844674407370955162
4) -1844674407370955161 to  1844674407370955161
5)  1844674407370955161 to  5534023222112865484
```

*Note: Ranges computed by running*:

```
python -c 'print [str(((2**64 / 5) * i) - 2**63) for i in range(5)]'
```

*Also depicted this way in MVP Robbie Strickland's [Cassandra High Availability](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1783989122)*.

Cassandra takes the hashed token value of the partition key (`user_name` in this case) and uses that to determine which node the row show be distributed to.  Given the hashed token values above, and the ranges that I have listed out, these are the nodes which each user name should go to:

```
Node 1: Helcine, Jebediah
Node 3: Patdard, Robo
Node 5: Bill, Bob, Valentina
```

Depending on your replication factor (RF), Cassandra may also place additional replicas of each row on other nodes.

Answer (score 1):

You can check where your data will be placed with `nodetool getendpoints`.

Below is simple example.

I'm using here `ccm` to create my cluster - https://github.com/pcmanus/ccm.

I will use your table users with the following keyspace configration:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE test_user WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 3};
```

So there will be 3 replicas.

First I create cluster with 5 nodes:

```
> ccm create -v 3.2 -n 5 test
```

start them:

```
> ccm start
```

and check if my cluster is up and running:

```
> ccm status                                   

Cluster: 'test'
---------------
node1: UP
node3: UP
node2: UP
node5: UP
node4: UP
```

Now I can check where data will be placed with `nodetool getendpoints`:

```
> ccm node1 nodetool getendpoints test_user users john;    

127.0.0.1
127.0.0.2
127.0.0.3
```

'john' will be on 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2, 127.0.0.3.

```
> ccm node1 nodetool getendpoints test_user users tom; 

127.0.0.3
127.0.0.4
127.0.0.5
```

'tom' will be on 127.0.0.3, 127.0.0.4, 127.0.0.5.