# how to handle search by unique id in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

I have a table with a composite primary key. **name,description, ID**

```
PRIMARY KEY (id, name, description)
```

whenever searching Cassandra I need to provide the three keys, but now I have a use case where I want to delete, update, and get just based on ID.

So I created a materialized view against this table, and reordered the keys to have ID first so I can search just based on ID.

But how do I delete or update record with just an ID ?

Comment: how many unique name and descriptions do you have per ID ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear if you are using a **partition key** with 3 columns, or if you are using a **composite primary key**.

If you are using a **partition key** with 3 columns:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
    id uuid,
    name text,
    description text,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY ((id, name, description))
);
```

notice the **double** parenthesis you need all 3 components to identify your data. So when you query your data by ID from the materialized view you need to retrieve also both `name` and `description` fields, and then issue one delete per tuple `<id, name, description>`.

Instead, if you use a **composite** primary key with `ID` being the only **PARTITION KEY**:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
    id uuid,
    name text,
    description text,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (id, name, description)
);
```

notice the **single** parenthesis, then you can simply issue one delete because you already know the partition and don't need anything else.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24953331/6570821) SO post for a clear explanation on *primary key* types.

Another thing you should be aware of is that the materialized view will populate a table under the hood for you, and the same rules/ideas about data modeling should also apply for materialized views.

Comment: yes its a composite primary key with 3 columns but if I make the table with just id, when i create the composite table I can only add one more column to search on.