# spring-data-cassandra: InvalidQueryException: Cannot execute this query ... use ALLOW FILTERING

Tags: spring, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-cassandra

I have the following code

```
  @Indexed
  @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "x", ordinal = 1, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
  @Column(value="x")
  private String x;

  @Indexed
  @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "code", ordinal = 2, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
  @Column(value="code")
  private String code;

@Query(value = "select * from customers where code = ?0")
Optional<Customer> findByCode(String code);
```

When this is executed, I get `Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING`.

Is there a way to avoid this just from `spring-data-cassandra`? I do not want to add `ALLOW FILTERING` in my query. I tried creating a separate index on the `code` column but this haven't solved the issue. I think it stops in the spring data configuration. If I execute the same query in `cqlsh`, it works.

Answer (score 3):

**You must specify partition key on your query, unless you create index or use ALLOW FILTERING**

Executing query with allow filtering might not be a good idea as it can use a lot of your computing resources and Might not return any result because of timeout. Don't use allow filtering in production Read the datastax doc about using ALLOW FILTERING

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html?hl=allow,filter

Comment: what does it mean in practice "specify partition key on your query" ? how to do that in the code?

Comment: For simple primary key, first field is the partition key. More on here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24953331/2320144

Answer (score 1):

When using a no-sql database, you need to properly design your data to avoid filtering. You can add a secondary index to optimize retrieval by a specific field. More details here: https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useSecondaryIndex.html

If you are sure that the query is what you need, you can use the `allowFiltering` parameter on the `@Query` annotation to explicitly indicate that `ALLOW FILTERING` be used.

```
@Query(value = "select * from customers where code = ?0", allowFiltering = true)
Optional<Customer> findOneByCode(String code);
```