# Unable to determine the reason for slow speed of Select query in Cassandra

Tags: python, python-3.x, cassandra

I have 100 million rows in cassandra's table. The schema is:
`id int, key varchar, row_hash varchar, version int` and the PK is: ((version), id). The query to create this schema is:

```
c_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} (id varchar, version int, row_hash varchar, PRIMARY KEY((version), id))".format( self.table_name )
```

Does this statement make the `version` as the Partition key?

Also, my select query which is apparently taking a long time as #rows keep on increasing is:

```
row_check_query = "SELECT {} FROM {} WHERE {}={} AND {}='{}' ".format( "row_hash", self.table_name, "version", self.version, "id", key )
```

Comment: For your first question I would take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949676/difference-between-partition-key-composite-key-and-clustering-key-in-cassandra).

Comment: @IftahP I actually wrote this code looking at that answer :p
Could you evaluate my concepts? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `version` is the partition key. `id` is a clustering column in your case.

You can use CQL Tracing to analyze your performance issues - https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshTracing.html

Depending on your data distribution you might get into a "wide row" scenario, having many records in a single `version` partition, having to read a very arge partition can take time.

Comment: it might, that depends on the client making the request. It will consume a lot of resources on the database.

Comment: If you are querying by the primary key columns uing equality, why are you using a compound key with a clustering column?
You should model your table to match your queries, in this case I would use both "version" and "id" as a composite primary key, a single partition.

Comment: So, if my version has, say, 1 billion rows and there can be millions of versions, what data model would you suggest? Yes, I will only query by version and id.

Comment: Use a composite key, having two columns as the partition key - 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} (id varchar, version int, row_hash varchar, PRIMARY KEY(version, id))