# Range query on clustering key

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a table where I am logging user activity performed on my website. My table structure looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE key_space.log (
    id uuid,
    time bigint,
    ip text,
    url text,
    user_id int,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC)
```

Now I want to fetch all the records which came in last 5 minutes.

For doing the same, I am using

```
select * from key_space.log where 
  time>current_timestamp - 5 minutes ALLOW FILTERING;
```

But this query is not returning any result & i am getting timedoutexception error. How to solve this problem? Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As with all Cassandra models, you'll need to start by building a table *specifically* designed to support that query.  Even if you could make it work with your current table, it would have to scan every node in the cluster, which would probably time-out (as you are seeing).

One way to do this will be to use a time "bucket" as a partition key.  If you just care about records for the last 5 minutes, then "day" should work, as long as you don't get millions of new records per day.  If you do, then you'll need a smaller time component for your "bucket."

```
CREATE TABLE log_by_day (
    id uuid,
    day bigint,
    time bigint,
    ip text,
    url text,
    user_id int,
    PRIMARY KEY (day, time, id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC, id ASC);
```

Now a query like this will work:

```
aaron@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT day,time,id,user_id FROM log_by_day
  WHERE day=201920 AND time > 1563635871941;

 day    | time          | id                                   | user_id
--------+---------------+--------------------------------------+---------
 201920 | 1563635872259 | 7fef03da-6c23-4bf2-9e98-fd126ab17944 |    1234
 201920 | 1563635872259 | 9a0c49ce-5ad2-45c5-b570-cd9de1c060d1 |    4607
 201920 | 1563635872209 | 9227166e-cda2-4909-b8ac-4168922a0128 |    2112

(3 rows)
```

Pro-tip: Partitioning on a unique `id` is great for data distribution, but doesn't give you much in the way of query flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Your table has *id* as the partition key and *time* as the clustering key. In order to run range query on clustering key, you need to specify the partition key also. So the query should be

```
 select * from key_space.log where id="xyz" and time>current_timestamp - 5 minutes ALLOW FILTERING;
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24953331/3921053) answer describes the different Cassandra keys very well.

Comment: I have to fetch all the records not just the records which came for id xyz.

Comment: That will not be possible in Cassandra. Even if you move "time" to partition key, then also you can not run range queries on a partition key.