# how can I store a record with 2 keys in a key value store?

Tags: cassandra, hbase, message, key-value-store

This is a semi theoretical question, Im studying system design and I havent worked with KV stores.
The question is about designing a chat app.

I have schema like this:

```
Message
PK | channel_id   bigint
   | message_id   bigint
_______________
   | user_id
   | content 
   | created_at
...
```

how would I organize this information to store in a Key - Value Store like Hbase, or Cassandra ?

Comment: What database/application you want to use? Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cassandra supports composite keys
So you can do a key of both `channel_id + message_id`

Example structure for your schema:

```
CREATE TABLE message ( 
   channel_id bigint, 
   message_id bigint, 
   user_id bigint, 
   content text,
   created_at date, 
   PRIMARY KEY (channel_id, message_id) 
);
```

However, cassandra keys are a bit harded then this.
With `PRIMARY KEY (channel_id, message_id)` you only define how to partition your data,
 but there's also CLUSTERING KEY option to define sorting

In this case it cound be
`PRIMARY KEY ((channel_id, message_id), created_at)`

Which would mean partition by `channel_id + message_id` AND sort a partition based on `created_at`.

Further read on keys in cassandra:
[Difference between keys in cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24953331/4551411)