# Primary Key without Clustering Key in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0

I want to use two fields as primary key (without clustering key).

PRIMARY KEY ((a, b)) => is that means a + b is the primary key, right? Or is it just partition key?

I'm confused

Answer (score 4):

A primary key definition of:

```
PRIMARY KEY ((a, b))
```

...sets *both* `a` and `b` as a *composite* partition key.  In this scenario, there is no clustering key.

This definition:

```
PRIMARY KEY (a, b)
```

...uses `a` as the partition key and `b` as the clustering key.

For more info, I recommend Carlo's famous answer to this question:

[Difference between partition key, composite key and clustering key in Cassandra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949676/difference-between-partition-key-composite-key-and-clustering-key-in-cassandra?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

To add to Aaron's response, the brackets (`(` and `)`) combine the 2 columns into one partition key. This means that you need to provide both columns in your filter in order to query the table:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE a = ? AND b = ?
```

Neither of these queries are valid because they only filter on 1 of the 2:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE a = ?
```

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE b = ?
```

For what it's worth, I've explained the terms "composite partition key" and "compound primary key" with some real examples to illustrate the differences in this post -- https://community.datastax.com/questions/6171/. Cheers!

Comment: Excellent addendum.  Thanks Erick!

Comment: If we set `PRIMARY KEY a`, that means primary key and partition key are `a`. If we set PRIMARY KEY ((a, b))`, that means partition key and primary key are `a and b`.  In that case if `a` is the same but `b` is different, these two data is stored in different partitions. Because `a and b` is a primary key (one row for each partition). If we set `PRIMARY KEY (a, b)`, that means partition key is `a` and clustering key is `b`. In that case if `a` is the same but `b` is different, these two data is stored in the same partition. Because the value of the partition key is the same. Am i right?

Comment: No, this is incorrect -- "In that case if a is the same but b is different, these two data is stored in different partitions." The partition key `(a, b)` identify where the partition is stored -- they are not 2 different partitions. Have a look at the link I posted for explanation. Cheers!

Comment: Your are right, but primary key is equal to the partition key if clustering key is not specified. am i wrong? `PRIMARY KEY ((a, b))` means each unique `a and b` is the unique partition and primary key. `PRIMARY KEY (a, b)` means data that has the same values of the `a` is goes to the same partition

Comment: Correct, primary key = partition key is there is no clustering column. And yes, BOTH `a` AND `b` uniquely identify the partition in the cluster. There is no `a`, there is no `b` -- but BOTH `a,b` only. Cheers!